# Why is my ContentPresenter taking up more space than the content it's presenting

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, controltemplate, contentpresenter

Now I don't know too much about control templates, but I'm trying to implement one following the article at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/control-templates/creating

Question 1:
As far as I can tell, the `ContentPresenter` of a `ControlTemplate` simply displays exactly the content defined in the view that consumes the `ControlTemplate`, nothing more or less. Is my understanding correct?

Question 2 (*I'll try my best to explain*):
If the answer to (1) is yes, why is my `ContentPresenter` taking up more space than my content? See

[image: screenshot]

My content is a `StackLayout` (green background) with `Grid` elements (pink background). Its dimension and position in the screenshot shown are exactly as I need. However, my `ContentPresenter` (red background) is expanding way beyond than its content (which is the green `StackLayout`).

If the answer to (1) is no, could the parent elements of the `ContentPresenter` (i.e, other elements in the `ControlTemplate`) be causing this?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit 1 (Code I'm using):**

The `ContentPresenter` in question belongs to a `ControlTemplate` targetting Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.MasterDetailControl, as follows:

```
<Style TargetType="uwp:MasterDetailControl">
        <Setter Property="ToolbarForeground" Value="{ThemeResource DefaultTextForegroundThemeBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="uwp:MasterDetailControl">
              <SplitView PaneBackground="Transparent" x:Name="SplitView" IsPaneOpen="{Binding IsPaneOpen,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMode="Overlay">
                <SplitView.Pane>
                  <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{TemplateBinding MasterToolbarVisibility}">
                      <Button Name="PaneTogglePane" Style="{StaticResource MenuButton}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <controls:DropShadowPanel Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource MasterMenuDropShadow}" Margin="12.5,0,0,0">
                      <StackPanel Background="Yellow">
                        <Grid>
                          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                          <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="Assets\master_menu_pointer.png" />
                          <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" />
                        </Grid>
                        <ContentPresenter Padding="0"
                                          Background="Red"
                                          Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Master}"
                                          Margin="0,-1,0,0" />
                      </StackPanel>
                    </controls:DropShadowPanel>
                  </Grid>
                </SplitView.Pane>
```

`Master` (in `Path=Master` above) derives from a `ContentPage` with `Content` defined in its code behind as follows:

```
Content = new StackLayout
{
  Children = {_firstPinkChild, _secondPinkChild},
  Padding = 15,
  Margin = 0,
  Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
  BackgroundColor = Color.Green,
  HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
  VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start
};
```

**Edit 2 (Some more styles being used):**

```
<Style TargetType="controls:DropShadowPanel" x:Key="MasterMenuDropShadow">
  <Setter Property="Color" Value="#595959"/>
  <Setter Property="OffsetX" Value="-2"/>
  <Setter Property="OffsetY" Value="0"/>
  <Setter Property="BlurRadius" Value="50"/>
  <Setter Property="ShadowOpacity" Value=".7"/>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="MenuButton">
  <Setter Property="Width" Value="{StaticResource AppBarThemeCompactHeight}" />
  <Setter Property="Height" Value="{StaticResource AppBarThemeCompactHeight}" />
  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
  <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
        <Grid Margin="0">
          <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
              <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source" Storyboard.TargetName="icon">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Assets\hamburger_onhover.icon.png"/>
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source" Storyboard.TargetName="icon">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Assets\hamburger.icon.png"/>
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="Disabled" />
            </VisualStateGroup>
          </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <Image Name="icon" Source="Assets\hamburger.icon.png" />
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

From official document,

> The `ContentView.Content` property is set to a `StackLayout` that defines the content to be displayed on the `ContentPage`. **This content will be displayed by the** `ContentPresenter` contained in the TealTemplate.

For better understand please look the follow screenshot. The display air of `ContentPresenter` is the red block that placed in the row 2, column 0-1.

[image]

Your content will be displayed in the `ContentPresenter`.

```
<StackLayout BackgroundColor="Green">
    <Label Text="Welcome to the app!" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    <Button Text="Change Theme"  />
</StackLayout>
```

So, the answer of the first question is true. For your second question, you need to post your xaml code. Maybe you wrongly define the display area of `ContentPresenter`.

Comment: Please see Edit 1.

Comment: Do you modify the style base on [`MasterDetailControl`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/MasterDetailControlStyle.xaml)? I could not implement your code in my side. You could share simple sample to me.

Comment: Yes, that's what I've based my style on. I've placed it in my UWP project's App.xaml, and it's working fine for me, other than this issue of course.

Comment: Sorry I wish I could but really can't. I simply don't have the time with my job to create a sample. Which is why I was hoping that asking about the fundamentals of how `ContentPresenter` works would answer my questions. According to what you've said, I shouldn't see any red but there's a lot of red beyond the green. This simply should not happen based on how I've set up my `ContentPresenter`. All it's supposed to do is display the green `Stacklayout` and that's it.

Comment: Yep, In my code I did not set color to `StackLayout`, so you could only  see `ContentPresenter` color. If I give `StackLayout` background value and it will cover  `ContentPresenter`.

Comment: That's ok. So is it giving the same result for you visually as it is for me?

Comment: I think the above code also works in your side, but I really could not implement your style. I can not find `DropShadowPanel` in my sdie. emm that's it.

Comment: DropShadowPanel can be installed using the NuGet package Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls. To use it in your XAML, use `xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"`.

Comment: PS: I'm using v2.0.0 of Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls in my UWP project. DropShadowPanel is pretty cool.

Comment: I will try to use it.

Comment: Does the rest of style same as official?

Comment: Yes, as far as i can remember, I haven't changed `SplitView.Content`, only `SplitView.Pane`, as that's where my focus is at the moment. So in my application, I get the screenshot (plus couple other elements above) for the master view.

Comment: I have create a sample with your style. but it throw exception can' find `MenuButton` ?

Comment: I think you need to share full xaml code so that I could reproduce the issue.

Comment: Please see Edit 2. You can get it to work by adding couple dummy 50px by 50px pngs to your UWP project's Assets directory: hamburger.icon.png, and hamburger_onhover.icon.png